# How to configure proxy server in polymer cli

Tags: polymer-cli

Is there any way to configure proxy server in polymer-cli ? similar to webpack-dev-server proxy. I've check any possible documentation with no success

Answer (score 5):

There are two proxy options you can set when running polymer serve:

*--proxy-path string*
Top-level path that should be redirected to the proxy-target. E.g. `api/v1` when you want to redirect all requests of `https://localhost/api/v1/`.

*--proxy-target string*
Host URL to proxy to, for example `https://myredirect:8080/foo`.

Starting with a proxy would look something like:

```
polymer serve --proxy-target http://localhost:3000 --proxy-path api
```

Answer (score 0):

to configure polymer-cli proxy in Linux, just set environment variable:

if you using bash,

```
export http_proxy="http://[proxy_host]:[port]"
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
export HTTPS_PROXY=$http_proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymer uses bower.
You can set proxy for bower and it will works fine.
create **.bowerrc** in your current project and add these lines :

`{
  "directory": "bower_components", 
  "proxy": "http://yourProxy:yourPort",
  "https-proxy":"http://yourProxy:yourPort",
  "no-proxy":"myserver.mydomain.com"
}`